# How to do multi logic value comparisons between dataframes?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes like so:

df1:

```
Email      DateTimeCompleted
2@2.com    2019-02-09T01:34:44.591Z
```

df2:

```
Email         DateTimeCompleted
b@b.com       2019-01-29T01:34:44.591Z
2@2.com       2018-01-29T01:34:44.591Z
```

How do I look up `Email` value in df2 and compare where `DateTimeCompleted` is greater than TODAY (minus) 90 days and append df1 row data into df2? To add sometimes df2 can be empty if that makes a difference.

df2 updated would look like this:

```
 Email         DateTimeCompleted
b@b.com       2019-01-29T01:34:44.591Z
2@2.com       2018-01-29T01:34:44.591Z
2@2.com       2019-02-09T01:34:44.591Z
```

I tried this:

```
from datetime import date    

if df1.Email in df2.Email & df2.DateTimeCompleted >= date.today()-90 :
    print('true')
```

i get error:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Also tried:

if df2.Email.str.contains(df1.Email.iat[0]):
    print('true')

got error:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:
1. `merge` the two dataframes on keycolumns `Email` so you know which rows consist in both dataframes.
2. Filter the rows which are greater than `today - 90days`
3. Concat the dataframes to final with `pd.concat`

Code:

```
# Merge dataframes together
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Email'], suffixes=['', '_2'])

# Filter the rows
df3 = df3[df3.DateTimeCompleted > (dt.today() - timedelta(90))]

# Drop the column we dont need
df3.drop(['DateTimeCompleted_2'], axis=1, inplace=True)

# Create final dataframe by concatting
df_final = pd.concat([df2, df3], ignore_index=True)

    Email   DateTimeCompleted
0   b@b.com 2019-01-29 01:34:44.591
1   2@2.com 2018-01-29 01:34:44.591
2   2@2.com 2019-02-09 01:34:44.591
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function to do the following

The function takes the argument

`mailid, dataframe1, dataframe2`

```
def process(mailid,df1,df2):
    if mailid in df2.Email.values:
        b = df1.loc[df1.Email==mailid,"DateTimeCompleted"].head(1)
        if((~b.empty) or (int(((pd.to_datetime('today'))-(pd.to_datetime(b))).astype('timedelta64[D]')) >90)):
            df1 = pd.concat([df1, pd.DataFrame([[mailid,b[0]]],columns=['Email','DateTimeCompleted'])],axis=0)
            print("Added the row")
        else:
            print("Condition failed")
            print("False")
    else:
        print("The mail is not there in dataframe")
    return df1
```